Expressing Frequency Bins as Period Bins
I'd like to change the x-axis of a Fourier transform frequency domain bar chart from frequency bins to period bins so that instead of displaying Hz or cycles/sec, I'm displaying sec/cycle; however, I think this would be problematic because the equal-sized frequency bins would not be of equal size due to the non-linear relationship between frequency and period.
For example, if I had a sample frequency $f_s = 1 Hz$ and wanted to bin that domain with bins of size $\Delta f_s = 1/512 Hz$ $\approx$ $0.002 Hz$, then I'd have 512 equally sized bins. However, if I wanted to represent that same domain in terms of period $T = 1/f_s$ so that I could discuss the results in terms of sec/cycle, then it seems that the bin sizes would not be equally spaced. The bin sizes would follow the following relation:
$\Delta T = \frac{\partial T}{\partial f_s}\Delta f_s = -\frac{1}{f_s^2}\Delta f_s$
I could use a non-linear scale to adjust it, maybe, but that might lead to a bar chart that's confusing or hard to interpret for some. Does anyone have any thoughts or experience with this?

perhaps you want to use a log scale for seconds/cycle?

Before using a log or other transformed scale I want to make sure whether or not it would be incorrect to make the horizontal scale 1/f_s = 1/(1Hz) = 1 sec/cycle wide and then dividing that scale into 512 equal bins of width 1/512 ~ 0.002 sec/cycle. Would that be wrong?

I don't have experience mapping $X(f)$ to $X(1/\tau)$ but I do with mapping $X(f)$ to $X(e^{\log(f)})$.  You interpolate between equally-spaced (in $f$) bins using something good (I used the cubic Hermite spline) and then sampled it at exponentially-spaced points (which are equally-spaced points in $\log(f)$.  For you it's a different mapping function.  It's not gonna be pretty for all values of $\tau$.

I had the feeling it would be involved. Thanks.

It's not that hard.  Check out the cubic spline for interpolation.  That's the only hard part and it ain't that hard.

I'll check it out, thanks.

Are there any packages out there that can do this and give an expression for the fit function?

It seems there's a way to do it using scipy but wanted to get other thoughts (link to scipy way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43458414/python-scipy-how-to-get-cubic-spline-equations-from-cubicspline)
